# UTF-8 characters in uploaded file name are jumbled on file upload

Tags: php, cakephp, encoding, iis-7, utf-8

I'm running a system on IIS7. The page META tag has the encoding as UTF-8, and the real encoding would appear to be the same according to the Chrome menu.

When I upload a file with a "long hyphen" in its name ("–") it gets converted to junk characters ("â€“").

The junk characters are saved in MySQL and the file name of the file on the server also has the junk characters. However when I pull the file name from the database and display it with PHP, it displays with the correct hyphen.

Is there any way to have the file name stored as UTF-8? When I try this code I get an error:

```
$fn = iconv("CP-1252", "UTF-8", $file['name']);
debug($fn);

Notice (8): iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `CP-1252' to `UTF-8' is not allowed
```

--

**Update several months later!**
So this problem is related to a PHP bug on Windows: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47096

Unicode characters get mangled by PHP on move_upload_file - although I have also seen the issue with rename and ZipArchive so I think it's a general issue with PHP and Windows.

I have adapted a workaround from Wordpress found [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/15955/allow-utf8-filenames-on-windows.2.php). I have to store the file with the mangled file name and then sanitize it on download/email/display.

Here are the adapted methods I'm using in case it's of use to someone in future. This still isn't much use if you're trying to zip files before downloading/emailing or you need to write the files to a network share.

```
public static function sanitizeFilename($filename, $utf8 = true)
{
if ( self::seems_utf8($filename) == $utf8 )
    return $filename;

// On Windows platforms, PHP will mangle non-ASCII characters, see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47096
if ( 'WIN' == substr( PHP_OS, 0, 3 ) ) {
        if(setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 0 )=='C'){ // Locale has not been set and the default is being used, according to answer by Colin Morelli at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788415/how-to-retrieve-the-current-windows-codepage-in-php
                // thus, we force the locale to be explicitly set to the default system locale
                $codepage = 'Windows-' . trim( strstr( setlocale( LC_CTYPE, '' ), '.' ), '.' );
        }
        else {
                $codepage = 'Windows-' . trim( strstr( setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 0 ), '.' ), '.' );
        }
        $charset = 'UTF-8';
        if ( function_exists( 'iconv' ) ) {

                if ( false == $utf8 ){
                    $filename = iconv( $charset, $codepage . '//IGNORE', $filename );
                }
                else {
                    $filename = iconv( $codepage, $charset, $filename );
                }
        } elseif ( function_exists( 'mb_convert_encoding' ) ) {
                if ( false == $utf8 )
                        $filename = mb_convert_encoding( $filename, $codepage, $charset );
                else
                        $filename = mb_convert_encoding( $filename, $charset, $codepage );
        }
}

return $filename;       

}

public static function seems_utf8($str) {
    $length = strlen($str);
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $c = ord($str[$i]);
            if ($c < 0x80) $n = 0; # 0bbbbbbb
            elseif (($c & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $n=1; # 110bbbbb
            elseif (($c & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $n=2; # 1110bbbb
            elseif (($c & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $n=3; # 11110bbb
            elseif (($c & 0xFC) == 0xF8) $n=4; # 111110bb
            elseif (($c & 0xFE) == 0xFC) $n=5; # 1111110b
            else return false; # Does not match any model
            for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) { # n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
                    if ((++$i == $length) || ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80))
                            return false;
            }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Indeed this is a PHP bug on Windows. There are workarounds like below, but the best solution I have seen is to use the [WFIO extension](https://github.com/kenjiuno/php-wfio). This extension provides a new protocol `wfio://` for file streams and allows PHP to properly handle UTF-8 characters on the Windows file-system. `wfio://` supports a number of PHP functions including fopen, scandir, mkdir, copy, rename, etc.

**original solution**

So this problem is related to a PHP bug on Windows: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47096

Unicode characters get mangled by PHP on move_upload_file - although I have also seen the issue with rename and ZipArchive so I think it's a general issue with PHP and Windows.

I have adapted a workaround from Wordpress found [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/15955/allow-utf8-filenames-on-windows.2.php). I have to store the file with the mangled file name and then sanitize it on download/email/display.

Here are the adapted methods I'm using in case it's of use to someone in future. This still isn't much use if you're trying to zip files before downloading/emailing or you need to write the files to a network share.

```
public static function sanitizeFilename($filename, $utf8 = true)
{
if ( self::seems_utf8($filename) == $utf8 )
    return $filename;

// On Windows platforms, PHP will mangle non-ASCII characters, see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47096
if ( 'WIN' == substr( PHP_OS, 0, 3 ) ) {
        if(setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 0 )=='C'){ // Locale has not been set and the default is being used, according to answer by Colin Morelli at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788415/how-to-retrieve-the-current-windows-codepage-in-php
                // thus, we force the locale to be explicitly set to the default system locale
                $codepage = 'Windows-' . trim( strstr( setlocale( LC_CTYPE, '' ), '.' ), '.' );
        }
        else {
                $codepage = 'Windows-' . trim( strstr( setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 0 ), '.' ), '.' );
        }
        $charset = 'UTF-8';
        if ( function_exists( 'iconv' ) ) {

                if ( false == $utf8 ){
                    $filename = iconv( $charset, $codepage . '//IGNORE', $filename );
                }
                else {
                    $filename = iconv( $codepage, $charset, $filename );
                }
        } elseif ( function_exists( 'mb_convert_encoding' ) ) {
                if ( false == $utf8 )
                        $filename = mb_convert_encoding( $filename, $codepage, $charset );
                else
                        $filename = mb_convert_encoding( $filename, $charset, $codepage );
        }
}

return $filename;       

}

public static function seems_utf8($str) {
    $length = strlen($str);
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $c = ord($str[$i]);
            if ($c < 0x80) $n = 0; # 0bbbbbbb
            elseif (($c & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $n=1; # 110bbbbb
            elseif (($c & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $n=2; # 1110bbbb
            elseif (($c & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $n=3; # 11110bbb
            elseif (($c & 0xFC) == 0xF8) $n=4; # 111110bb
            elseif (($c & 0xFE) == 0xFC) $n=5; # 1111110b
            else return false; # Does not match any model
            for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) { # n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
                    if ((++$i == $length) || ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80))
                            return false;
            }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say your page is set for UTF8, which means your iconv() arguments are backwards. The syntax is

```
iconv($original_char_set, $new_charset_to_convert_to, $string_to_convert);
```

You're uploading a UTF-8 filename, but then telling PHP to convert that string TO utf-8, as if it was cp1252. Since cp-1252 is a single byte charset, all of the high-order utf-8 escape sequences are getting trashed.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but even though I'm uploading a UTF-8 filename, it seems to be treated as something else on the other side of POST. I tried reversing them and got the same error. I tried changing CP-1252 to ISO-8859-1 and it said illegal character. I reverse them back and it doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't get rid of the junk (in fact it just adds more in the form of "Ã¢Â€Â“".
Latest function is: iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $file['name']);
With ISO & UTF swapped, it says illegal character, presumably because it's looking for the junk character in UTF-8 & it doesn't exist?

Comment: if the client-side page is set as utf, then the data (including filename) should be sent as utf. you shouldn't have to convert anything at all. Just make sure **EVERYTHING** is set for utf8: client->server->mysql->table->field.

Comment: I should add, I'd ideally like a way to solve this (if it exists!) that doesn't involve iconv() because it would involve changing every file upload function in our application.

Comment: How do I verify that the original page is UTF-8? In Chrome I go to Tools, Encoding and "Auto Detect" is enabled and UTF-8 selected.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8>` and whatnot.check the page headers (including http headers), and then check the headers of the response. generally the client should send things back in the same format the page arrived in.

Comment: Also what is confusing is as per original post, even though the MySQL entry and the actual file name have the junk character, it displays on the page without it.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47096

[2017-04-11 15:59 UTC] ab@php.net
Fixed in 7.1, see UPGRADING.

Thanks.