# PHP Upload File containing arabic filename

Tags: php, iis, unicode, utf-8, fastcgi

I am trying to upload files that are named in Arabic but it is saving in folder like ØµÙ†Ø§Ø

I am using PHP 7 with IIS

I have tried to use iconv even the filename i am printing is coming right before move_upload_file but once this called the file store in unicode charcaters
I have tried to give header but it didn't work.

All the pages are encoded in UTF-8 with meta tags

Answer (score 0):

The NTFS, if that is the file system that your system is using, doesn't support all unicode characters, sadly. Essentially, the system when it saves the file isn't able to find the characters so it is replacing it with the closest characters that are available to it.

To solve this however, you might want to change the name of the file to something that isn't using special characters while you move it. I recommend a hash (eg. md5 or other) of the file content, so that it is unique. This will store the file locally and make sure that even if a file is uploaded with characters that your system can't handle, you are still able to access the content later.

Answer (score 0):

look like this is some issue in PHP as mentioned in below link:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47096

to resolve the issue you could use php-wfio extension as a workaround. This extension provides a new protocol wfio:// for file streams and allows PHP to properly handle UTF-8 characters on the Windows file-system. wfio:// supports a number of PHP functions including fopen, scandir, mkdir, copy, rename, etc.

[UTF-8 characters in uploaded file name are jumbled on file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408377/utf-8-characters-in-uploaded-file-name-are-jumbled-on-file-upload)